# MS Word template can only be opened as read only

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word

I have a MS Word template on a server that is used to create reports programmatically (with C# .NET).
The problem is that when an instance of this template is opened on server A, the template can no longer be edited on server B and vice versa. Opening it on server A and editing the template there is not a problem. (Trying to edit the template gives a message about opening it as read only or opening a copy)

I suspect this is a MS Office problem rather than a problem with how the template was opened.

So far I've tried saving the newly created document, but even after closing and opening it, the 'link' with the template persists and the template cannot be edited.
I also checked the template and the "Automatically update document styles" property is turned of in the addins and templates menu.

Is there any way to break this 'link' between the instance and the template?